# How to get separate z scale for multiple levelplots (lattice)

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

Here is my attempted code.

```
attach(mtcars) 
levelplot(mpg ~ wt * hp|gear, data = mtcars,labels=FALSE ,scales=list(relation="free"))
```

The result is this plot.
[image]

I wish to know how to (1) add local z colorbar for each levelplots and (2) how to make each levelplot's title shows as gear 4, gear 3 and gear 5 instead of just "gear". The desired result is something like this following figure (the colorbar is here is cut-and-paste so it isn't local range like it should be). I have checked help and look up online but couldn't find a solution yet. 
[image: Desired plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `mtcars$gear` is of class `"numeric"`, you plot is using the "shingled" strip style associated with numeric conditioning variables. It sounds like you'd rather gear number be treated as a categorical variable, so you should convert it to a `"factor"` before conditioning on it.

Here's what I would do:

```
gearFac <- factor(mtcars$gear, levels=3:5, labels=paste0("gear", 3:5))
levelplot(mpg ~ wt * hp|gearFac, data = mtcars,
          labels = FALSE, scales = list(relation="free"))
```

[image]

Comment: @chengvt -- Ah, I missed that first question. Unfortunately, I'll have no time to answer that other one now or for a few days. I'm pretty sure that **lattice** plotting functions have **no** support for multiple colorbars. My suspicion, then, is that the easiest solution will be to make three separate plots (one for each level of gear), and then arrange them by hand, using (for example) `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`. Best of luck!

Comment: Got it by using **gridExtra** package!